# ajax with multiple records to insert into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a block of code which is a dynamically generated div with a form (based on array loop) that has dynamic inputs which are added by a button:

```
<?php foreach($tickerDisplays as $key => $ticker):?>

    <form id="Items" method="post">
        <label id="ItemLabel">Item 1: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Items[]"><br/>
        <button type="button" class="moreItems_add">+</button>

        <input type="hidden" name="tickerID" id="tickerID" value="<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="saveTickerItems" value="Save Ticker Items">  
    </form>

<?php endforeach;?>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("button.moreItems_add").on("click", function(e) {
var tickerID = $('#tickerID').val();
  var numItems = $("input[type='text']", $(this).closest("form")).length;
  if (numItems < 10) {
    var html = '<label class="ItemLabel">Item ' + (numItems + 1) + ': </label>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="Items[]"/><br/>';
    $(this).before(html);
    console.log(tickerID);
  }
});

</script>
```

That code above is working and simply allows the '+' button to add a new input. I'm getting the input values as well as the tickerID from my hidden input in preparation for ajax submission. I'm getting what I expect from the serialized form but I have an issue.

The following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Items").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $("#Items").serialize();
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Prints this:

```
Items%5B%5D=this&Items%5B%5D=is&Items%5B%5D=test&tickerID=1
```

Which I expect. The problem is that with my ajax call to my mysql insert function, I need to insert one record for each value plus the tickerID. My sql insert is inserting into columns tickerID and content. So for the above console.log, I would need the following insert:

```
tickerID   |   content
----------------------
1               this
1               is
1               test
```

How can I properly pass my form data to the ajax and then do something like a foreach in order to insert multiple  records?

ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#Items").submit(function(e) {

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: addticker.php,
       data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});

</script>
```

addticker.php

```
$tickerID = $_POST[''];
$content = $_POST[''];

$addTicker = "
    INSERT INTO tickerTable (tickerID, content)
    values ('$tickerID', '$content');
"
$mysqlConn->query($addTicker)
```

Comment: User serializeArray() instead of serialize()

Comment: How exactly can I use that with each input mapped to the hidden input though? Will it do that by default?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ it will create an object like {input_name: value, ...}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

```
    $items = $_POST['Items'];
    $tickerID = $_POST['tickerID'];

    foreach ($items as $item){

        $addTicker = "
            INSERT INTO tickerTable (tickerID, content)
            values ('$tickerID', '$item');
         "
         $mysqlConn->query($addTicker);
    }
```